# ansible playbook when: condition ec2 tag is set

Tags: ansible

Folks,
  I'd like to run a simple command, lets say setting a hostname, if an ec2 tag is set on an instance.  Consider the following:

```
- name: Gather facts
  action: ec2_facts

- name: Get instance ec2 facts
  action: ec2_facts
  register: ec2_facts

- name: Get resource tags from ec2 facts
  sudo: false
  local_action: ec2_tag resource={{ec2_facts.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_instance_id}} region={{ec2_facts.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_placement_region}} state=list
  register: ec2_tags

- debug: msg="{{ ec2_tags.tags }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK: [foo | debug msg="{{ ec2_tags.tags }}"] *****************************
ok: [10.1.15.119] => {
"msg": "{'role': 'foo', 'Name': 'YAY', 'service': 'web', 'env': 'dev'}"
}
```

So now, I'd like to do the following:

Set a hostname, if the `ec2_tags.tags.Name` exists.  *How do i use this in a playbook* ?  This seems to fail:

```
- name: friendly hostname
  hostname: name={{ec2_tags.tags.Name}}
  when: {{ec2_tags.tags.Name}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`when: ec2_tags.tags.Name is defined` should do it